# How to cancel a specific task in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I recently was working with jupyter notebook and I didn't saved it, my last checkpoint was an hour ago. I decided to download the file in `pdf via latex` format and it stuck.
The output on my PowerShell was

```
[I 15:27:39.761 NotebookApp] Building PDF
[I 15:27:39.767 NotebookApp] Running xelatex 3 times: ['xelatex', '.\\notebook.tex', '-quiet']
```

And it was stuck here. Now is there any way that I can only stop this specific task which is Running xelatex and/or Building PDF so that I do not have to restart my kernel and do not waste my data. Thanks.

---